# Does the ORM read_group on Odoo 11 has the same features of Odoo 12?

Tags: group-by, orm, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am working on an Odoo 11 project and unfortunately, we can't migrate to Odoo 12.

Reading the book [Odoo 12 Development Cookbook - Third Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/product/odoo-12-development-cookbook-third-edition/9781789618921) I found a way to create my aggregate method WITHOUT coding `SQL` with `GROUP BY`, just using the `read_group` method available on Odoo API.

Here is what I do to get it using SQL:

```sql
SELECT SUM(ai.amount_total) as sum_total,
       AVG(ai.amount_total) as avg_total
  FROM account_invoice as ai
 WHERE ai.partner_id = :partner_id AND ai.type = 'out_invoice'
```

And here is how I am trying to get it working on my model class:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):

   # fields definition

    @api.multi
    def get_aggregated_invoices(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        invoices_partner_domain = [
            ('partner_id', '=', self.partner_id.id), 
            ('type', '=', 'out_invoice')
        ]
        grouped_result = self.env['account.invoice'].read_group(
            invoices_partner_domain,
            [
                'partner_id', 
                'sum_total:sum(amount_total)',
                'avg_total:avg(amount_total)'
            ],
            ['partner_id']
        )
        if len(grouped_result) > 0:
            print(str(grouped_result)) # << DEBUG breakpoint here
            return {
                'sum_total': grouped_result[0]['sum_total'],
                'sum_total': grouped_result[0]['avg_total'],
            }
        else:
            return None
```

Debugging the code I got this result:

[image: Group Result]

Am I missing anything or Odoo 11 does not have the same features as Odoo 12?
If not, is there any way to do it through Odoo API or should I need to stick with my `GROUP BY` SQL statement instead?

Answer (score 1):

The v12 version introduces the use of aggregation functions in [fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L2077) parameter.

> **:param list fields:** list of fields present in the list view specified on the object.
> Each element is either `field` (field name, using the default aggregation),
> or `field:agg` (aggregate field with aggregation function `agg`),
> or `name:agg(field)` (aggregate field with `agg` and return it as `name`).
> The possible aggregation functions are the ones provided by PostgreSQL
> (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)
> and `count_distinct`, with the expected meaning.

The difference is in the process of the aggregated field in the [_read_group_raw](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L2148) function, Odoo will try to use the aggregation function if defined and [valid](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L196), if not it will use the field `group_operator` as an aggregation function.

Odoo 11 will not check if we defined an aggregation function and use the `group_operator`. In your example, the [aggregated_fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/odoo/models.py#L1984) will be an empty list.

The default `group_operator` for `amount_total` field is `sum`. If you use the SQL debug level, you will see that Odoo executes the following query:

```
SELECT min("account_invoice".id) AS id, count("account_invoice".id) AS "partner_id_count" , sum("account_invoice"."amount_total") AS "amount_total" ,"account_invoice"."partner_id" as "partner_id"
            FROM "account_invoice" LEFT JOIN "res_partner" as "account_invoice__partner_id" ON ("account_invoice"."partner_id" = "account_invoice__partner_id"."id")
            WHERE (("account_invoice"."partner_id" = %s)  AND  ("account_invoice"."type" = %s))
            GROUP BY "account_invoice"."partner_id","account_invoice__partner_id"."display_name"
            ORDER BY  "account_invoice__partner_id"."display_name"
```

When calling the `read_group` function as following (use `sum`  as an aggregation function):

```
grouped_result = self.env['account.invoice'].read_group(
            invoices_partner_domain,
            [
                'partner_id',
                'amount_total',
            ],
            ['partner_id']
        )
```

Comment: Got it, but it works only with the aggregate function `sum`. For the `avg` we still need to use a SQL statement, right?

Comment: It uses the field `group_operator` as an aggregation function and unfortunately you can't use `read_group` to get `avg_total`, you will need the SQL statement.